# Convert multiple format date into only one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a date column in df which needs to align the format.

The column has multiple formats at the moment such as 20201203, 05/06/20, 2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400.
My expected results need to be in YYYY-MM-DD format, I tried `pd.to_datetime(df, format='%Y-%m-%d')`before, but then received 2 errors  `05/06/20 doesn't match format specified` and `second must be in 0..59`

I assume that there would be some initial codes to pre-process the data, is it true. Or is there any proper function? Please help.

Thank you so much, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['20201203', '05/06/20', '2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400']
})
```

**Two options**

**First**

```
df.Date = df.Date.str.split(' ',1).str[0] ## If `'2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400'` is a valid date in your df.


df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

**Second**

```
for i in range(len(df['Date'])):
    df['Date'][i] = parse(df['Date'][i])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df
```

**Output**

```
    Date
0   2020-12-03
1   2020-05-06
2   2019-09-15
```

Comment: The third element is not `2019-09-15 00:00:00.1568480400` but `2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400`

Comment: Updated the answer for `2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400`. Since we don't need time field hence we can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_datetime` function without `format` parameter. Let Pandas infer the datetime format:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["20201203", "05/06/20", "2019-09-15 00:00:00.1568480400"]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

```py
>>> df
         date
0  2020-12-03
1  2020-05-06
2  2019-09-15
```

**Check your input data**:
`2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400` is not valid:

```py
ParserError: second must be in 0..59: 2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400
```

Comment: Seems like this answer is exactly same as mine.

Comment: nw, two people can think in similar fashion :)

Comment: Many great thanks to Corralien and @Uts for the answers ;) I executed the code successfully with "2019-09-15 00:00:00.1568480400", but my df really has this format "2018-07-03 00:00:1530550800" (not one but many rows :( ). Is there any way to help this? Sincerely appreciated ^^

Comment: Already answer is added for it in @Uts answer `First option`  -- Use this -- `df.Date = df.Date.str.split(' ',1).str[0] ## If `'2019-09-15 00:00:1568480400'` is a valid date in your df.` and then `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`